# SignalR not broadcasting when service action entered remotely

Tags: signalr

I have an Action entry in my web api odata service. It works fine. Any message that arrives is logged to disk, so I KNOW the message is arriving there. If I call this action from a client application anywhere on my network, the message is logged to disk and using SignalR I broadcast the message to my listening javascript client. This all works perfectly.

If I call the very same Action entry, using the very same client application, but from a different network, then the message STILL arrives just fine. The message and all of its data are logged to a disk file just fine. However, SignalR will not broadcast message. I have written the message data to my log file one statement before broadcasting with SignalR, so I know I have valid data to be broadcast. Here's my action entry point. Again, there's nothing wrong with this code because I receive the message here just fine EVERY time.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("MyResponse()")]
    public IHttpActionResult MyResponse(ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        IHttpActionResult retVal = null;
        BridgeResponse bridgeResponse = null;

        try
        {
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                bridgeResponse = (BridgeResponse)parameters["bridgeResponse"];
                if (bridgeResponse != null)
                {
```

I have a startup file where I do my initialization:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(XXXXX.Startup))]
namespace XXXXX
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR("/Beacon", new HubConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my hub.

```
[HubName("Beacon")]
public class Beacon : Hub
{
    private static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Beacon>();

    public static void SendMessageToHub(string data, String To)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.All.displayData(data);
    }
}
```

Not much too it. My javascript client has the "displayData" method where the data is displayed. Again, this all works perfectly if I call my action from anywhere within my network. If I call the action from a different network everything works EXCEPT SignalR broadcast.

This one has stumped me for a couple days now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add more infos about what you mean by "different network". Also, how is the app hosted?

Comment: What's the reason/background for using static methods within the hub?